# How to stop installing app every time when tests run in xamarine.uitest

Tags: c#, xamarin, automation, xamarin.android, xamarin.uitest

I am new to mobile testing and working to test a native app using Xamarine.UITest on an android in which I am executing multiple BDD scenarios . Every time I run tests it installs the app again and I lose the data created by previous scenarios. How can I stop installation of app when app is already installed and check if installed skip installation and just launch the app. Below is the piece of code which I am using to install the app and return IApp. Thanks for looking into it.

```
public static IApp StartApp(Platform platform)
{
    if (platform == Settings.Platform)
    {
        return ConfigureApp
                .Android
                .InstalledApp(Settings.AUTPackageName)
                .StartApp();
    }
    return ConfigureApp
            .iOS
            .StartApp();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using AppDataMode.DoNotClear in the app initializer? Something like this: app = AppInitializer.StartApp(platform, Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.AppDataMode.DoNotClear)

Comment: @Saamer thanks for your reply. I tried your above code then I get error "No overload for method "StartApp" take two arguments". So got rid of platform argument and supplied just one but still for every test it's installing and deleting the data for previous scenario :(

Comment: Yeah from my personal knowledge and experience it always reinstalls, but maybe you could create an issue in the Xamarin UI Test repo or ask Brminninck on Twitter

Comment: Brandon Minnick https://twitter.com/thecodetraveler @brandon-minnick ?

Comment: thanks @Saamer for raising it :)

Answer (score 0):

So I've run into the other side of this -- I have some different run behavior on first load, so I *want* to force it to install clean sometimes.

What I've found is that Android and iOS devices have different behavior on this. With Android, using the InstalledApp will always rebuild the application, it will check against the installed version and install the new build if different. Loss or caching of data is effected by the `AppDataMode`.

So, if the issue is the *building* of the application, because it can be slow on a slow machine, I'd suggest looking at using a pre-built APK file to run the tests, using `.ApkFile("")` instead of `.InstalledApp`.

If the concern is the loss of data (which is more what your question sounds like), then you should do something like:

```
    {
        _app = ConfigureApp
                .Android
                .InstalledApp(Settings.AUTPackageName)
                .StartApp(AppDataMode.DoNotClear);
    }
```

iOS is a different beast, but I think you're looking at Android specifically here.